# Reliable button presses captured in polling program

Tags: python, tkinter, mouse, polling

I'm Newbie (sorry... but thanks in advance)

I've spent the weekend reading questions and looking at examples in so many places that I've lost my mind.

I'm building a polling program that reads I/O from various sources.
While I'm polling, I need the user to be able to click on part of the screen to cause an action or go to another GUI page for a while before returning here.  If he leaves this page, I can suspend the polling required by this root page.

My issue is that I cannot get reliable mouse clicks or mouse position from the bind.  I've depopulated most of the code to get to basics shown below.  I'm totally missing how to accomplish this, which should be a typical use case?

```
from tkinter import *

## Set the key variables
myTanks = [20, 30, 50, 80]
activeTanks = len(myTanks)

## Functions Defined Below
def motion(event):
  print("(%s %s)" % (event.x, event.y))

def click(event):
  print("clicked")  

def readTankLevels(activeTanks):
    global myTanks
    print (myTanks)
    for i in range(0,activeTanks):
        print("Reading Tank ", str(i))
        ##  I inserted the following line to emulate the network activity and processing in the real program
        root.after(500, print("Waiting "+str(i)))

def drawTank():
    print("Drawing the Tanks in GUI")

def updateLabels():
    print("Updating the tank labels")
    t1Holder=Canvas(root, width=(100), height=50, bg="black", highlightbackground="black")
    t1Holder.bind('<Button-1>',motion)
    t1Holder.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=0)

    t2Holder=Canvas(root, width=(50), height=75, bg="blue", highlightbackground="black")
    t2Holder.bind('<Motion>',motion)
    t2Holder.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=0)

##  Open GUI
root = Tk() 
root.wm_title("Tank Monitor") 
root.config(width=300, height=200, padx=0, pady=0, background = "black")

##  Body of program
while True:
    ## Continuous poll of the tanks being monitored
    readTankLevels(activeTanks)
    drawTank
    updateLabels()
    root.update()

print ("You should never get here!")   

mainloop()
```

Comment: drawTank is missing ()

Comment: This doesn't do what you think: `root.after(500, print("Waiting "+str(i)))`. It calls `print` _immediately_. `after` requires a _callable_.

Comment: the missing () is an artifact of my stripping the real code down to this size... fixed it in this sample, but it isn't part of my confusion about how to accomplish a polling GUI with screen updates at same time as monitoring mouse (or touchscreen in my case) inputs.  I don't know how to schedule tasks or use "interrupts".

Comment: I don't actually use that root.after() in my real code, just knew that when I used the time.sleep that it isn't good with tkinter.  I was just trying to chew up a half second to emulate the device reads (which can go to 2 seconds if each device isn't present and the socket times out.  I'm happy to get pointed in a direction that will help me understand how to achieve my top level need to read I/O periodically, monitor mouse clicks and take actions from the mouse clicks "immediately". Thanks

Comment: I put a function call on the After so now have: root.after(5000, sleeper(1)) and the sleeper function has a print and I threw in a root.update (and tried some other lines in there with no real progress).

Comment: one basic question is if the bind can be to a function or has to be in the mainline or doesn't matter?  I've tried both with no improvement.  Current status:  only very occasionally do I record a mouse movement, and clicks are very slow to respond but get about 80% of them if I intentionally go slow and don't click again before the first click is recorded.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up learning about how 'after' really works via experimentation and wanted to post the answer for others that must have similar issues.

The 'After' command places the function call on the queue of things to do, with a timestamp on when to do it.
While that interim period ensues, the interpreter is basically sitting at the mainloop() command (in my case i do this by design vs having other code running during this period).
In doing it this way, the interpreter can service all mouse movements and button presses very quickly.
I'm now able to have a truly effective GUI.  I was not able to find this specific answer anywhere I looked, as most posts just say to use this instead of sleep under Tkinter, but don't provide the details of what it actually does.

Note that it is important to re-establish the 'after' command within the loop that is called to function.  In my case I wanted to read sensors every 10 seconds, so the line before mainloop() is the after command, and in the def, i copy the same line of code to recall the 'after' every 10 seconds. (showing as 2 seconds below to make demo quicker).  This should help anyone in the boat I was in...

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk() #Makes the window
root.wm_title("Remote Sensor Dashboard")

## initialize variables

## def's piled in form many functions below

def readSensors():  ## Get sensor data from web connected devices
    print("sensors have been read")
    updateGUI()
    root.after(2000, readSensors)

def updateGUI(): ## redraw each affected frame or canvase
    print("GUI has been updated")

def updateMousePosition(event):  ## Print the coordinates of the mouse (can also bind to clicks)
    print("(%s %s)" % (event.x, event.y))


#Create window that has your mouse targets (use buttons, color wheels etc)
mouseHouse = Frame(root, width=200, height = 200, bg="black")
mouseHouse.bind('<Motion>',updateMousePosition)
mouseHouse.grid()

## Initial Read of Sensor Network
root.after(2000, readSensors)

## Peform Initial GUI draw with the Sensor Data
print ("GUI has been drawn")

mainloop()
```